# Assembly Jump with Multiple plus or do plus before jump (performance)

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, micro-optimization

in Assembly, if i have a JUMP table with the address of over 2000 labels:

```
.TABLE:
     DD .case0
     DD .case1
     DD .case2
     DD .case3
     DD .case4
     ...
     ...
     ...
     DD .case2000
```

which way is better for addressing to jump:

way 1:

```
mov    r12d, .TABLE    ; r12d or any other registers
mov    ebx, [r13d]     ; r13d holds the id of case * 4 so we don't need to '4 * ebx'
add    ebx, r12d       ; ebx = address for Jumping
jmp    ebx
```

way 2: (Same way 1 but `'add ebx, r12d'` is removed and changed to `'jmp [ebx+r12d]'`)

```
mov    r12d, .TABLE    ; r12d or any other registers
mov    ebx, [r13d]     ; r13d holds the id of case * 4 so we don't need to '4 * ebx'
jmp    [ebx+r12d]
```

way 3:

```
mov    ebx, [r13d]     ; r13d holds the id of case * 4 so we don't need to '4 * ebx'
jmp    [ebx + .TABLE]
```

in the 'way 1', we have source code size problem due to extra functions but i think it has better performance than other ways in jumping because im going to have about 2000 jumps (Irregular jump (May be from case0 to case1000 or ...)

So for jumping performance, which way is better in a source code that has a lot of JUMP ?

Comment: Way 1 should end with `jmp [ebx]` otherwise it'll jump into the middle of the jump table. Also if you're using registers that are only available 64-bit mode you should probably be doing 64-bit address calculations.

Comment: Don't overthink it.  Go with the third way, which has the fewest instructions.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm fewest instructions is not always a solution !

Comment: @Ross Ridge  r13d is not a 64-bit mode register !!!! the 64-bit register for r13d is r13 !!!!

Comment: R13D is a 32-bit register that's only available in 64-bit mode. !!!!

Comment: @Ross Ridge aha good point ... i searched about it and you right ... sry (thank you for that)

Comment: You may visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if there is no bug/error/malfunction etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 32-bit address size is a good choice if you can get away with it to compress the jump table vs. using qword pointers for 64-bit mode.

Otherwise you'd want to load 16-bit or 32-bit offsets (`movzx` or `mov`) and add to some 64-bit base address from a RIP-relative LEA for 64-bit code.  (Which also makes it position-independent).

> fewest instructions is not always a solution !

But in this case fewest instructions is also fewest uops.  `[disp32 + reg]` addressing modes are efficient.

If you were going to consider using more instructions, it would be to load the pointer into a register for `jmp reg` instead of using `jmp [mem]`, not simplifying addressing modes even more.

https://agner.org/optimize/ shows that `jmp mem` on Intel Sandybridge family is still only 1 fused-domain uop, with the load micro-fused into the port 6 jump uop. 
 So a separate `mov` load would actually cost *more* uops in the front-end.

(An indexed addressing mode would probably unlaminate; `jmp [.TABLE + ebx*4]` would cost 2 uops for the issue/rename stage but still only 1 in the decoders and uop cache.  But it seems you have a byte offset stored in memory for some reason, so you don't need a scaled index.)